# Is Chrome buggy when it comes to css transitions?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, css-transitions

I'm making my div's of auto height disappear with nice transitions. I accidently found what I think is a bug in Chrome 31.0.

I've attempted to do a workaround since css3 can't handle transitions to/from auto height (there's lots of posts about that subject). So I have this code:

```
$(document).on("click","#test",function(){
    var r =$(this).css("height")
    $(this).css("height", r)
    var foo = $("#test").css("height")
    $(this).addClass("test")

    $("#test").css("opacity","0")
    setTimeout(afterWait,1000)
})
```

This works and looks really nice. See my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/n3g83/1/. However, I have no need for the foo variable, but if I remove it the transition stops working as it should.

In FF and IE it works in both cases.

So anyways, I thought this might be useful for others struggling with this :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [All you need to know about CSS Transitions](http://blog.alexmaccaw.com/css-transitions):

> [...] you’ll find that if you apply both sets of properties, one immediately after the other, then the browser tries to optimize the
>   property changes, ignoring your initial properties and preventing a
>   transition. Behind the scenes, browsers batch up property changes
>   before painting which, while usually speeding up rendering, can
>   sometimes have adverse affects.
>
> The solution is to force a redraw between applying the two sets of properties. A simple method of doing this is just by accessing a DOM
>   element’s offsetHeight property [...]

When your code invokes `.css("height")`, [jQuery internally access the element's `offsetHeight`](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/24e587929f62428e1959b10aace6dc4fd65ab397/src/css.js#L112) property which forces a redraw. Without this, Blink and Webkit will batch up the styling changes made by `.css("height", r)` and `.addClass("test")`.

If you don't like the call to `.css("height")`, you can replace it with anything else that forces a redraw, e.g. accessing the element's `offsetHeight` property:

```
this.offsetHeight;
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/n3g83/2/)

I've asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564942/clean-way-to-programmatically-use-css-transitions-from-js) looking for a clean solution but apparently there's none yet.

Firefox had a similar behavior until not long ago (Firefox 23 had the same "bug") but it was fixed, so we can hope that Blink and Webkit may fix it in the future.