# removeClass is not working w/CSS transitions

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to make a blink effect on click (instantly set background and then fade out) but on second click `removeClass` is not removing it. Where is a mistake?

JS:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).css({transition: '0s'}).addClass('qwe')
    .delay(1).queue(function() {
        $(this).css({transition: '2s'}).removeClass('qwe');
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
div{
    height: 100px;
    width: 100px;
    background: gray;
}
.qwe {
    background: green;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6cTeY/23/)**

Comment: Fixed wrong fiddle link

Answer (score 3):

The browsers are built to optimize consequent style changes by coalescing them. In case of CSS transitions they do it a bit over-zealously.

Currently there's no 'clean' way around it, the best you can do in current browsers is force restyle via `window.getComputedStyle(document).color` or similar before the applying the changes that would invoke transition (`removeClass` in your case).

See 
[Clean way to programmatically use CSS transitions from JS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18564942/clean-way-to-programmatically-use-css-transitions-from-js) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it using jQuery UI

```
$('div').click(function() {
    $(this).addClass('qwe').switchClass('qwe', '', 1000);
});
```