# Why do I need a value of '0' in setTimeout for my transition to work?

Tags: javascript, css-transitions, settimeout

I'm trying to use the classList api combined with CSS transitions to prepend an item to a list, remove a class that's making it transparent, and then fade it in.

html

```
<ul id="container">
    <li>test1</li>
    <li>test2</li>
    <li>test3</li>
    <li>test4</li>
</ul>
```

css

```
.is-transparent {
    opacity: 0;
}

#container {
    li {
        -webkit-transition: opacity 2.3s;
        -moz-transition: opacity 2.3s;
        transition: opacity 2.3s;
        &.is-transparent {
            opacity: 0;
        }
    }
}
```

js

```
function runner() {
    var container = document.getElementById('container');
    var newItem = document.createElement('li');

    // item attrs
    newItem.innerText = 'test Above';
    newItem.classList.add('is-transparent');

    // do work
    container.insertBefore( newItem, container.firstElementChild );

    // transition opacity (ideally)
    newItem.classList.remove('is-transparent');
}
```

I'd expect this to work since the class gives it 0 opacity and when it's removed it should have opacity: 1; but it doesn't: http://jsfiddle.net/7TpY6/1/

Adding a setTimeout of 0 (as follows) makes the transition work: http://jsfiddle.net/3N2Bn/1/

```
window.setTimeout(function(){
    newItem.classList.remove('is-transparent');
}, 0);
```

Why?

Comment: I havent got the slightest clue but what made you even try a setTimeout of 0?

Comment: [css transitions on new elements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12089264/402037)